# Roof Segment center and Bounding Box

Tags: geolocation

When i request building insights for a special location, i get four roof segments.But they all have the same center Position and the bounding boxes of the roof segments also have the same sw and ne. They have the same values as the whole roof.  Is this a bug?

i see the same issue in the Example building insights request:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/solar/building-insights

Comment: Please add more details. What are you trying to accomplish? What are you doing to try to make it work? Provide any code or URLs you're having problems with.